# Fetch out parameter of procedure from another procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

A procedure has an out parameter,

```
OUT_RESULT         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
```

and it returns like:

```
 OPEN OUT_RESULT FOR
        SELECT   code
                 name,
                 some_val
          FROM   aTable;
```

When I call this procedure from other procedure, how can I access this out param

eg -

```
 create or replace 
PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS 
OUT_RESULT sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
 callingProc (OUT_RESULT);
END TESTPROC;
```

How do I loop and get code,name,someval out of OUT_RESULT?

Something like:

```
LOOP
         FETCH out_result INTO SOMETHING;
         EXIT WHEN out_result%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
```

Comment: `OUT_RESULT` after invocation of the procedure whose parameter it is ( i assumed the latter is `callingProc` in your example ).

Comment: yes. how to fetch the result of OUT_RESULT and print?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Hello below mentioned code snippet will definitely help you out.



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_ref(
            p_lst OUT sys_refcursor )
        AS
        BEGIN
          OPEN P_LST FOR SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
        END;

/* Creating test_ref_1 SP which calss the test_ref procedure and provides the refcursor output given by test_ref procedure. */

        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_REF_1(
            cur_out OUT sys_refcursor )
        AS
        BEGIN
          test_ref(cur_out);
        END;


    --------------------------To Execute ----------------------------------------------
        var p_lst refcursor;
        EXEC TEST_REF_1(:p_lst);
        PRINT :p_lst;

    --------------------------To Execute ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: would really appreciate if you guide me with the syntax for oracle stored procedure

Comment: @user209357612: The first part of the answer is CREATING procedure which returns ref_cursor. Second step is CREATING Procedure which calls the first procedure and gives a REFCURSOR ouotput.

Comment: I understand that. But to access value of var p_lst refcursor;
    EXEC TEST_REF_1(:p_lst); in oracle proc.. i need the syntax for that

Comment: We cant do any kind of maipulation over Refcursor. We need to convert this refcursor output to COLLECTION to access/Manipultae the resultset.

Comment: Exactly. If you can help me with manipulation syntax, it would be a great help

Comment: how to access -SELECT   code
                 name,
                 some_val
          FROM   aTable; as out_result and display